# java - generic type ignored by a compiler

Tags: java, generics

recently I've stumbled upon an edge case with generics that doesn't seem logical.

I've got a simple interface that returns a list of children:

```
public interface INode<C extends INode> {

    List<C> getChildren();

}
```

I would expect that if the INode type is referenced without defining the C type, the C type would be inferred by a compiler as the INode. In other words, in below code:

```
    public void retrieveChildren(INode node)  {

        var children = node.getChildren();

    }
```

children would be inferred as of `List<INode>` type. Instead, it's just plain List.

Worth noting that type inference works as expected with the INode method returning a single element, so when this interface:

```
public interface INode<C extends INode> {
    
    C getFirstChild();
    
}
```

is used in the following method:

```
    public void retrieveFirstChild(INode node)  {

        var firstChild = node.getFirstChild();

    }
```

firstChild is propely inferred as INode.

Is there a rationale for the jdk to work like that? Also, is there a clean way to enforce a C type for a returned list?

Many thanks.

Comment: "children would be inferred as of List type. Instead, it's just plain List", you mean "children would be inferred as of List<INode> type. Instead, it's just plain List"?

Comment: Hi @Eugene thanks for spotting that out. Yes, that's what I meant, stackoverflow formatted it as a tag and it wasn't displayed.

Answer (score 5):

> children would be inferred as of List< INode> type. Instead, it's just plain List.

Once you use raw types, it infects everything. `INode` has typeargs, and in your signature (`retrieveFirstChild`), you use it raw, which means all interactions that involve any generics with that variable are also raw.

The solution is to not use raw, ever (the compiler warns, and you should heed these warnings!):

```
public void retrieveFirstChild(INode<?> node) {
 // note the <?> up there!
    var firstChild = node.getFirstChild();
}
```

now firstChild's type is `INode`, as expected.

Comment: That's absolutely awesome. Thank you for the refresher on the basics!

Comment: @elm Also, you should add a generic at the interface definition. Either `C extends INode<C>` (an INode returns children of the same type as itself) or `C extends INode<?>` (an INode returns children of any INode impl)

Comment: @Eugene I would explain that with 'you should heed those warnings'. I don't think it's a smart idea to dump the full JLS on generics in here. 18 pages is a bit much, perhaps/

Comment: You can assign a raw type to a `List<INode>`, yes, but you can't do so without getting a compiler warning. Instead of explaining how to (ab)use raw types, all that needs to be said is: Don't ignore that warning, fix it. At which point, your situation does not exist. Please stop brigading my answers. There's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: my bad, I was not trying to do that, I even upvote your answer; but anyway I'll delete the comments here and will stop commenting under any of your answers from now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you really want is:

```
public interface INode<C extends INode<C>> {

   List<C> getChildren();

   C getFirstChild();

}
```

Since you are using a raw type here :

```
 public void retrieveChildren(INode node)  {

     var children = node.getChildren();

}
```

you are going to apply *erasure* to `INode`, and the erasure of that is `INode`, i.e.: `C extends INode` is going to be erased to `INode`. That is explained in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> To facilitate interfacing with non-generic legacy code, it is possible to use as a type the **erasure of a parameterized type** or the erasure of an array type whose element type is a parameterized type. **Such a type is called a raw type**.

And that is visible because of two things:

```
INode first1 = node.getFirstChild(); // works
```

and if you de-compile the actual `.class` file (`javap -c -p -v`), you will see :

```
InterfaceMethod DeleteMe$INode.getFirstChild:()LDeleteMe$INode;
```

or in plain english `getFirstChild` returns an `INode`.

On the other hand `List<C> getChildren();` since it itself uses generics, will be erased to `List`, without type arguments. So these will both compile, for example:

```
 List<INode> children1 = node.getChildren();
 List<String> children2 = node.getChildren();
```